# Can I see entering command in ATOM with VIM_MODE_PLUS plugin?

Tags: plugins, atom-editor

When I enter command in ATOM with VIM_MODE_PLUS plugin finnaly it works fine. But I can't see what I've enter to check before put Enter. Is this possible to see entering command or may be required additional configuration?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it help but you can toogle the key binding resolver with :

`Ctrl-.` on Windows or `Cmd-.` on Mac